# How find all string, text from one file in two file - python

Tags: python-3.x

I have:

dane.txt

```
ala
cot
bat
napaaaa
tom
```

bat tom know item

dane1.txt

```
bat
tom
```

How can I find all string, text from dane1 in dane.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

zrodlo1 = open('dane.txt', 'r')
zrodlo2 = open('dane1.txt', 'r')
docelowe = open('wynik.txt', 'w')

for wiersz2 in zrodlo2:
    for wiersz1 in zrodlo1:        
        if wiersz1 == wiersz2:
            docelowe.write(wiersz2)

docelowe.close()
zrodlo1.close()
zrodlo2.close()
```

Comment: It's not clear from this code how it is really formatted, which might make a difference. Also, are the contents of the file all on one line or separate lines? If you show exactly what you are doing we are better placed to help

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks, but i modificated file and not work correctly:
I need find all row where there are ala and adam.

dane.txt

ala is akaakkaka 
tomek
artur 
house adam 
ala

dane1.txt

ala 
 
adam

some_output_file.txt

ala is akaakkaka 
house adam 
ala